# How can I pass parameters using powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Someone can tell me if is possible pass variables when i call Remove-Printer command on Powershell?

> Remove-Printer -Name 'Printer1 (Copy $i)'

Idk if this is possible but i tried this:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 5; $i ++) {
   Remove-Printer -Name 'Printer1 (Copy '+$i+')'
}
```

and more unsuccessful attempts...

If someone can help me... thanks you.

Comment: I don't known much about PowerShell, but I believe that you don't need the `+` to concatenate strings; probably `'Printer1 (Copy $i)'` will work. Check this: [For-Loop](https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-for-loop/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes tells PowerShell that there are character literals inside. Just use double quotes, and $i had a space after it (the $i++ part) in the for loop constructor.

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 5; $i++) {
   Remove-Printer -Name "Printer1 (Copy $i)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I forgot to comment that I need to execute this from cmd and does not accept  " when i execute #PowerShell -Command "...."

Comment: Solved! 

PowerShell -Command ""for ($i=0; $i -le 5; $i++){Remove-Printer -Name """Printer1 (Copy $i)"""}""

Comment: You should be able to lose the beginning and trailing quotes. (before for and after the closing bracket)